# Database shows up in App_Data & not in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know why my database won't show up in SQL Server, but will show up in `App_Data`? I did code first migration and update the database but still can't see it. Please help

I try changing the connection and it did not work

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Rentals.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Rentals;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

No database shows up

Comment: what does it show some message like table doesnt exists if this is the message in console then you need to check the access to that database

Comment: this is my connection string:'<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Rentals.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Rentals;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>'

Comment: I updated the question with the connecttion string